# Unexpected token Error

Tags: compile-error

I've created a custom button called Commit and I'm trying to call the following method using `action = {!.commit}`,

Apex below

[image: Unexpected token: commit line 113]

Do I need to do anything else to be able to call commit in my VF?

Comment: After removing dot.. still getting error...

Comment: Not sure why my previous comment was deleted, {!.commit} was a typo. I'm getting an Compile error on Line 113 after PageReference

Comment: Can you post more code here?

Comment: Error Error: BPSection Compile Error: The method void save() is referenced by Visualforce Page (BrokerProfileSection) in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. at line 113 column 17 - That's the new error. I've removed all reference to the save(), thanks @ Keith C

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is probably that "commit" is a reserved word in Apex so you can't use it as a method or variable name. (When the compiler encounters such a word it has special meaning, it's part of the language.) Use a different name in the code and in the Visualforce.

Apex has a lot of these - see [Reserved Keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm).

Comment: This really great to know.. Keith C.. have you used this keyword some where. I never used this. I am just wondering where salesforce used this keyword.

Comment: @Ratan No I haven't; I think they just reserved the word in case they ever wanted to introduce the concept in the future.